# How do I turn non-uniform data into a transverse dimension in an ncl environment

Tags: ncl

This is a user who uses NCL
I want to visualize the results of the model

As a learning position, the professor who teaches me told me to draw without remappingThis model uses a cubed sphere grid
So, the result is not lat or lon, but only one dimension called gird

But when I drew the contour plot, I used sfXArray and sfYArray as resources, so it was drawn well

But when I tried to draw a wind vector, I only applied 2D, so there was a problem
I tried setting up UDataArray and VDataArray using vector resources, but the following error occurred

```
fatal:Number of dimensions in parameter (1) of (gsn_csm_vector) is (1), (2) dimensions were expected
```

This is the resource I set up

```
  vecres = True
  vecres@gsnDraw = False
  vecres@gsnFrame = False
  vecres@vcGlyphStyle     = "CurlyVector"
  vecres@vcRefMagnitudeF  = 5
  vecres@vcRefLengthF     = 0.045
  vecres@gsnRightString   = " "
  vecres@gsnLeftString    = " "
  vecres@tiXAxisString    = " "
  vecres@vcRefAnnoOrthogonalPosF = -.535

  vecres@vfXArray = f->lons
  vecres@vfYArray = f->lats

  vecres@vfUDataArray = f->u_m(0,20,:)
  vecres@vfYDataArray = f->v_m(0,20,:)
```